# How can we read value have just insert in transaction

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I am working on TRANSACTION MySql and I have a problem:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO a(name) VALUES("hello");
SELECT * FROM a WHERE name = "hello";
COMMIT/ROLLBACK;
```

So I can not find the value I have just added into table a. Please help me if there is any way to SELECT value that have just added.

Thanks a lot

Comment: commit first and then select

Comment: @nbk thanks for your comment, but I want to commit after finish all my queries because I have to check many conditions before commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the auto increment ID value for the row you just inserted, you can get it with `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

If you want the whole row you just inserted, do this, assuming your table's autoincrement id is called `id`.

```
INSERT INTO a whatever;
SELECT * FROM a WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

You don't need an explicit transaction for this  sequence of queries to work correctly. But, you can still use one for other purposes.